# Identifying outliers based on Y values

Tags: outliers

Is it possible to identify outliers from the Y not from X data?
I mean if I want to remove data having a big difference of Y values not X values.

Thanks

Comment: Of course you can... A little background or the tool you are using would help.

Comment: It is data obtained by simulation and then used into a model for learning. I am using python with pandas, sklearn and sometimes statsmodels. I am new to this field and I wonder if I have to do it just by replacing X data by Y or if there are other things to take into consideration. thanks again.

Comment: Well, it is common to remove extreme points from the data set before using it, be it x, y or in any other dimension. I am not familiar with the tools you listed and whether they allow you to automatically detect outliers, but if swapping x and y would allow you to do this, I think it is a valid approach.